# textbox value to database

Tags: textbox, database-connection

I have two forms, when I click my button, it must add the values of the textboxes to the database and display it in the second form "Debtors".
The problem I'm having, is that I'm not getting the "Debtors" to capture the data in the datagrid.

```
private void DebAddBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\simeo\source\repos\SparesPOS\SparesPOS\PartsPosDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

        StringBuilder strSQL = new StringBuilder();
        strSQL.Append("Insert into DebtorData values(");
        strSQL.Append("@DebtorID, @DebtorName,@DebtorPhone1,@DebtorPhone2,");
        strSQL.Append("@DebtorFax,@DebtorEmail,@DebtorAddr1,@DebtorAddr2,");
        strSQL.Append("@DebtorAddr3,@DebtorAddr4,@DebtorPostCode,@DebtorContact1,");
        strSQL.Append("@DebtorContact2,@DebtorLimit)");

        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DebtorID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DebIDtxt.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DebtorName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = DebNametxt.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DebtorPhone1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = DebPh1txt.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DebtorPhone2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = DebPh2txt.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DebtorFax", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = DebFaxtxt.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DebtorEmail", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = DebEmtxt.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DebtorAddr1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = DebAdr1txt.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DebtorAddr2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = DebAdr2txt.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DebtorAddr3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = DebAdr3txt.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DebtorAddr4", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = DebAdr4txt.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DebtorPostCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = debPosCtxt.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DebtorContact1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = DebCont1txt.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DebtorContact2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = DebCont2txt.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DebtorLimit", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = DebLimittxt.Text;

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = strSQL.ToString();
            cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
            cmd.Connection.Open();

            try
            {

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch { }
        }
        Debtors form = new Debtors();

        form.Refresh();
        form.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how to post an mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add details regarding what your specific problem is (error message, etc.).

Comment: After some tampering and testing, I realized that the data was being captured by the database, but the form "Debtors" is not updating the data, when I close the app and run it again, and then view the Debtors form, the data is added, but obviously thats not ideal.

Comment: I added this code after I posted.Debtors form = new Debtors();
            
            form.Refresh();
            form.Show();